# how to get product quantity in observer

Tags: magento2, stock, quantity

I'm working on magento2.4 .Need to get the quantity of the product in product save after observer.
while get qty it always returns null for newly created products.

Note:qty shows correctly for updating the product.

```
    <?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); 
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        $stockData = $stockItem->getQty();

    }   
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you have in th eobserver?

Comment: updated the code @Marius

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get the quantity of a newly created product in the catalog_product_save_after observer:

```
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

    class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $_stockRegistry;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
        ) {
            $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        }

        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
            $qty = $stockItem->getQty();
            
            // Do something with the quantity information
        }
    }
```

In this example, we're using the StockRegistryInterface to get the stock information for the newly created product.

Comment: Not working..still qty is null for new products

Comment: ok wait let me update my code... could you please confirm a case like when you create a new product in Admin then right after that you want a qty of that product right ?

Comment: yes,want qty while creating new products in admin